# playing Vimeo in a Lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox, vimeo

Strelok has the right answer; however, on first click nothing happens (till second click). After this the video will not load and I cannot get the lightbox to close.

Can anyone help tweak it further?

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">album name</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://vimeo.com/13844810" class="lightbox_trigger" data-videoId="13844810">"Winter"</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">album name</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">video name</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
 $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var videoId = $(this).data("videoId");

       if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {
            $('#content').html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+videoId+'" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>');
            $('#lightbox').show();
        } else {

            var lightbox =
                '<div id="lightbox">' +
                '<p>Click to close</p>' +
                '<div id="content">' +
               '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+
                videoId +
            '" width="320" height="240" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

            $('body').append(lightbox);
        }
     });

    $('#lightbox').on('click', function () {
        $(this).hide();
   });
```

Comment: make you of modal div jQuery ui http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Answer (score 1):

You can ofcourse use an existing lightbox plugin that supports video. But as coding excercise you can have a look how I modified you lightbox to play vimeo videos in an embedded player:

http://jsfiddle.net/rQqVj/2/

1. It uses `data-videoId` attribute to specify the video id of the vimeo video to play.
2. It uses the universal player from [Player Embedding on Vimeo](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding) developer page.